# How to open a UIViewController on a UITableViewCell click?

Tags: ios

I want to apply this (https://www.paxxio.in/checkout/onepage/) functionality in my app, I don't have idea that how will I apply this logic. Please see the above url.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Comment: Have you implement tableView in your class?

Comment: yes i added a uitablview, how will i open a uiview in it.

Comment: you are using xib or storyboard?

Comment: i am using storyboard

Comment: by `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: Have you added didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

Comment: can anyone give me some tutorial link for the same task i want

Comment: yes i already add it

Comment: Than write your code to open a uiviewcontroller in that method.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0):

Did not understood your question much though, if you want to open a view controller on tableviewCell click you can use tableview delegate method

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

inside this method you can load the view controller.

Now loading view controller can be done in many ways.

In case you are using story board and segue:
you can simply call

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your segue identifier" sender:your view controller instance (optional)];
```

If you are using story board n yet not using segue then you can instantiate a view controller from story board identifier

```
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your story board" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@" identifier of view controller you want to load"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

If you are not using story board then instantiate view controller from xib :)

Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: thanks bro, but if you see my url link in my question. i want to open a view below the uitableview cell, and if another cell is click then one view will hide and other will open just below it

Comment: am sorry I did not see that :| my mistake :| So you need a collapsible tableview cell isn't it???

Comment: I did it long back, unfortunately i dont have code with me now buddy but i can give you logic you can build on it :)

Comment: before we move on to logic one doubt this view of yours that appears below cell is same view that appears below cells with different values? or different cells for each cell??? :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99172/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-sandeep-tomar).

Comment: yes sir i want to open a different view with different values for every cell

Comment: I sent you a link in chat friend :) can you check that out :) I guess you will get a fair idea of how to do it :) I also followed a similar tutorial :P

Comment: In case you din get the chat here it is

Comment: There are many tutorials available on collapsible tableview cell here is another one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Collapsable-Table-View-for-iOS. Idea is fairly simple expand the cells height based on if cell is tapped to extend or not